# blender 2.9 hide / reveal not working properly?

Tags: edit-mode

I have on various occasions using the latest 2.9.01 version of blender, hidden items in edit mode, then pressed alt + h, to reveal, and a strange thing happens.  The items do not always show again.  Instead when I leave edit mode, items are still hidden also as well as in edit mode, and even the other hidden items do not reveal.  Instead I have to press 1,2,3, to cycle through some sort of hierarchy group-hiding that seems to have occurred, then after this it seems to work again.

Am I pressing something "new" in blender that is different in 2.9 that causes this to happen or is this a bug?

Comment: are your objects in edit mode? try not-edit-mode and then hit atl-H also.. you can use eye in project hierarchy.

Comment: @MFarooqi  both don't work as stated.

Comment: could you please shre some screen shot?

Comment: @MFarooqi  No.  How am I supposed to show "the invisible man".  Think about what  you are asking before asking please.